# What is contained in the files that end with "wiz.digit(s)"?

Tags: nethack

I was recently looking in the files that pertain to NH343, and found some files that start with my computer's name.  Some were easily identified as saved games because they have the character's name following.  But there are quite a few more that have my computer's name followed by   -wiz.0, -wiz.5, -wiz.49, etc.   I can't open them like a normal doc, and the curiosity is getting to me.  Are they bones files, like I suspect, or something altogether different?

Comment: After reading the wiki on bones, I'm inclined to think they are bones.  The number indicates dungeon level.  You might find that wiz is replaced by another shorthand for a character such as Bar, Rog, etc..  I'm not entirely sure of how to find the "playground," but what I've read says that's what these are.

Comment: oops, mine level +4,  So, 0would be L4, and 49 has to be Moloch's Sanctum.  I died there once, so now I have a1/3 chance f getting bones there now.  That's my guess.

Comment: nope, Moloch's Sanctum is ineligible for bones, as is VS.  So my math was totally off.  And I'm even more confused.

Comment: Ok, after re-reading wiki, I found the real bones files.  They actually start out  "bon" then they have an alphanumeric indicator as to level.  Still, no clue as to what the wiz files are.